# RXJS error in epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) from 'redux-observable'

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs

Can not solve this issue, system expects ',' instead of '.' in line `import { epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) } from 'redux-observable';`
However, I wrote according to official documentation.

That is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) } from 'redux-observable';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/root';
import { rootEpic } from './epics';


const epicMiddleware = epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));

const appWithProvider = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);


ReactDOM.render(appWithProvider, document.getElementById('root'))
```

That is an error message:

```
./src/index.js
  Line 7:24:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   5 | 
   6 | import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
>  7 | import { epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic) } from 'redux-observable';
     |                        ^
   8 | import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   9 | import rootReducer from './reducers/root';
  10 | import { rootEpic } from './epics';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is wrong , you should import like below

```
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { rootEpic } from './epics';
```

and use it like this

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```